# How to sort a whole matrix without having to convert it to a one dimensional array

Tags: c#, sorting, multidimensional-array

My task in school was to make a c# program that will sort a whole matrix and I've already sorted it by converting it into a regular array etc. However, I'm having problems with finding a way to do it without one dimensional arrays.

I tried to find a solution by searching online and I couldn't find anything except sorting the array by row/column.

Comment: Show us..what you have tried..so far

Comment: you have 2 loops for sorting a one-dimensional array, you need another 2 loops for two-dimensional array

Comment: Please add your code so we understand what you ahve done so far and what you are actually asking for.

Comment: "sort a whole matrix" can mean many things. You need to specify.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a mapping for `(i) -> (j, k)` where `i` is an one dimensional index and `(j, k)` are the coordiantes of your matrix entries. Then you can implement any sorting algorithem based on `i`.